# Detection of variable length pattern in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, iteration

The last 2 columns of a timeseries indexed dataframe identify the start ('A' or 'AA' or 'AAA'), end ('F' or 'FF' or 'FFF') and duration (number of rows between start and end) of a physical process, they look like this:

[image]

and the A-F sequences or the n sequences between them are of variable length.

**How can I identify these patterns and for each of them calculate averages of other columns for the corresponding rows?**

What I, very badly, tried to do is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd


##### EXCEL LOAD
filepath= 'H:\\CCGT GE startup.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name='Sheet1',header=0,skiprows=0,parse_cols='A:CO',index_col=0)
df = df.sort_index() # set increasing time index, source data is time decreasing

gas=[]

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if df['FLAG STARTUP TG1'] is not 'n':
        while 'F' not in df['FLAG STARTUP TG1']:
          gas.append(df['PORTATA GREZZA TG1  -  m3/h'])
          gas.append(i)
```

But the script gets stuck on the first if (doesn't match the 'n' condition and keeps appending the same row,i pair). Additionally, my method is also wrong in excluding the last 'F' row that still pertains to the same process and should be considered as part of it!

p.s. the first 1000 rows df is here http://www.filedropper.com/ccgtgestartup1000

p.p.s. Besides not working, my method is also wrong in excluding the last 'F' row that still pertains to the same process and should be considered as part of it!

p.p.p.s. The 2 columns refer to 2 different processes/machines and are unrelated (almost, more on this later), I want to do the same analysis on both (they will refer to different columns' averages). The first "A" string marks the beginning of the process and gets repeated until the last timestamp that gets marked with an 'F' string. in the original file the timestamps are descending and that's why i used the sort_index() method. The string length depends on other columns values but the obvious FLAG columns correlation is only in the 3 character strings 'AAA'&'FFF' because this should occur only if the the 2 processes start in +-1 timestamp from each other.

Comment: Besides not working, my method is also wrong in excluding the last 'F' row that still pertains to the same process and should be considered as part of it!

Comment: FYI: You can [edit] your question to include new information.

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific.  Your dataset has two FLAG STARTUP columns; are they related?  Independent?  Your dataset has an FF before any AAs.  If FF is an end marker, what should we do with the data before?  You often have multiple AAs in a row.  Is that the start of multiple processes, or does only the first one carry any meaning?  Etc.

Comment: The 2 columns refer to 2 different processes/machines and are unrelated, I want to do the same analysis on both (they will refer to different columns' averages). The first "A" string marks the beginning of the process and gets repeated until the last timestamp that gets marked with an 'F' string. in the original file the timestamps are descending and that's why i used the sort_index() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to get the desired results (N.B. I later decided that only the single character 'A'-->'F' sequences are of interest)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

##### EXCEL LOAD
filepath= 'H:\\CCGT GE startup.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name='Sheet1',header=0,skiprows=0,parse_cols='A:CO',index_col=0)
df = df.sort_index() # set increasing time index, source data is time decreasing

tg1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.copy(),columns=['counter','flag','gas','p','raw_p','tv_p','lhv','fs'])
k = 0 
for i,row in df.iterrows():
        if 'A' == str(row['FLAG STARTUP TG1']):
          tg1.ix[i,'flag']=row['FLAG STARTUP TG1']
          tg1.ix[i,'gas']=row['Portata gas naturale']
          tg1.ix[i,'counter']=k
          tg1.ix[i,'fs']=row['1FIRED START COUNT  -  N°']
          tg1.ix[i,'p']=row['POTENZA ATTIVA  MONTANTE 1 SU 400 KV  -  MW']
          tg1.ix[i,'raw_p']=row['POTENZA ATTIVA  MONTANTE 1 SU 15 KV  -  MW']
          tg1.ix[i,'tv_p']=row['POTENZA ATTIVA  MONTANTE TV  -  MW']
          tg1.ix[i,'lhv']=row['LHV -  MJ/Sm3']

        elif 'F' == str(row['FLAG STARTUP TG1']):
          tg1.ix[i,'flag']=row['FLAG STARTUP TG1']
          tg1.ix[i,'gas']=row['Portata gas naturale']
          tg1.ix[i,'counter']=k
          tg1.ix[i,'fs']=row['1FIRED START COUNT  -  N°']
          tg1.ix[i,'p']=row['POTENZA ATTIVA  MONTANTE 1 SU 400 KV  -  MW']
          tg1.ix[i,'raw_p']=row['POTENZA ATTIVA  MONTANTE 1 SU 15 KV  -  MW']
          tg1.ix[i,'tv_p']=row['POTENZA ATTIVA  MONTANTE TV  -  MW']
          tg1.ix[i,'lhv']=row['LHV -  MJ/Sm3']
          k+=1 

tg1 = tg1.dropna(axis=0)
tg1 = tg1[tg1['gas'] != 0] #data where gas flow measurement is missing is dropped
tg1 = tg1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

#timestamp count for each startup for duration calculation
counts = pd.DataFrame(tg1['counter'].value_counts(),columns=['duration'])
counts['start']=counts.index
counts = counts.set_index(np.arange(len(tg1['counter'].value_counts())))

tg1 = tg1.merge(counts,how='inner',left_on='counter',right_on='start')
 # filter out non pertinent startups (too long or too short)

tg1 = tg1[tg1['duration'].isin([6,7])]

#calculate thermal input per start (process)
table = tg1.groupby(['counter']).mean()
table['t_in']=table.apply((lambda row: row['gas']*row['duration']*0.25*row['lhv']/3600),axis=1)
```

Any improvements and suggestions to do the calculations in the iteration and avoid all the "prep- work" after it are welcome.